# Unable to set a UIBarbutton back to the default tint color

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uibarbuttonitemstyle

If I change the tint of a UIBarbutton how can I reset it to it's default tint.

Here I am set a custom tint for a button...

```
examCancelButton.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel;
examCancelButton.tintColor = myRedButtonTint;
```

Then later I need to set it back to it's default style and tint. So I thought just setting the style to UIBarButtonItemStyleDone would do the trick like this...

```
examCancelButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
```

But the color remains red. I can set it to a nice blue color on my own, but I would like to get the default color of a UIBarButtonItemStyleDone button. Is this possible?

Thanks, John

Comment: Did you try setting `tintColor` to `nil`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`examCancelButton.tintColor = nil;`

Comment: Works for UIButtons too. [dataProtectionButton setTitleColor:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];